# How do I access Cloud SQL from App Engine with SQL Alchemy?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to use **Flask SQLAlchemy** to establish a database connection between Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL.

I am able to establish the connection in a **Flex** environment but not **Standard** whenever I deploy. I am not sure why this is the case. I am receiving this error response from the Error Logs:

`OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol)")`

This is the connection string I am using to connect to the Cloud SQL database
`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://<username>:<password>@/<database>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<instanceName>'`

When testing and developing locally, I am able to use this connection string to connect to the database through the cloud_sql_proxy but this connection string fails when I deploy and attempt to access it externally.

I've looked through similar questions but haven't seen any that reference this specific error response yet.

I am using the Second Gen Cloud SQL version

Comment: This looks promising...
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/340

Comment: Where do you specify the host name in this line:`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://<username>:<password>@/<database>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<instanceName>'`?

Comment: It is specified with `<database>`